# $p,2p+1$ and $(p+1)/2$ are all primes

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

If we assume that $p$ an odd prime and let $2p+1$ and $\frac{p+1}{2}$ both be primes, then must $p=3,5$?

Comment: Write down each of $p,2p+1$ and $\frac{p+1}{2}$ for $p=7,11,13,17,19,...$, and see if you can find common factors that show that $2p+1$ and/or $\frac{p+1}{2}$ is not prime for these $p$. This will give you an idea as to how the argument has to be executed.

Comment: Did you mean $p$ where you typed $q$ in the title?  One of them is divisible by $3$

Comment: Yes, shoud be $p$ in the title, sorry!

Answer (score 3):

For primes $p\ge7$, $p\equiv\pm1\bmod3$. If $p\equiv1\bmod3$ then $2p+1\equiv0\bmod3$. If $p\equiv-1\bmod3$ then $(p+1)/2\equiv0\bmod3$ and $(p+1)/2>3$ so it is composite. This leaves us $p=3,5$ to check, and we get the title's result.

Comment: Many thanks, that is great!

Comment: @jack2020 Please accept my answer and we'll be done with it.